# Why the output of Dense Optical Flow in OpenCV is not continuous？

Tags: opencv, opticalflow, object-tracking

## I want to track whether worker throw garbage into the truck manually in the video.

[image: worker throw]

**Q1: Is Dense Optical Flow in OpenCV a good solution for me?**

**Q2: I tried to code a sample. But why the flow image is not continuous?**

frame 41 and 43 is good , but frame 42 is black
[image: good frame 41]
[image: bad frame 42]
[image: good frame 43]

**Q3: Can I spy on the color change in a small area to track if garbage through ?**

small area like this:
[image]

here is my code. you can run my code and video in my github repository

https://github.com/Pinocchio2018/QuestionHelper/blob/main/openCV_related/dence_optical_flow_problem/test.py

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv


def put_frame_no(image, frame_no):
    # font
    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    # org
    org = (50, 450)

    # fontScale
    font_scale = 2

    # Blue color in BGR
    color = (0, 0, 255)

    # Line thickness of 2 px
    thickness = 2

    # Using cv2.putText() method
    image = cv.putText(image, "frame no: " + str(frame_no), org, font,
                       font_scale, color, thickness, cv.LINE_AA)

    return image


cap = cv.VideoCapture(cv.samples.findFile("0116-sample4-edited-short-throw.mp4"))
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prv_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[..., 1] = 255

cv.namedWindow("flow image", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow("flow image", 800, 600)


frame_no = 0
while 1:
    ret, origin_img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print('No frames grabbed!')
        break
    next_frame = cv.cvtColor(origin_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prv_frame, next_frame, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    mag, ang = cv.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
    hsv[..., 0] = ang * 180 / np.pi / 2
    hsv[..., 2] = cv.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    flow_image = cv.cvtColor(hsv, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    flow_image = put_frame_no(flow_image, frame_no)
    origin_img = put_frame_no(origin_img, frame_no)

    frame_no += 1

    vis_frame = np.concatenate((origin_img, flow_image), axis=1)

    cv.imshow('flow image', vis_frame)
    # cv.imshow('origin', flow_image)

    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv.imwrite('opticalfb.png', origin_img)
        cv.imwrite('opticalhsv.png', flow_image)
    prv_frame = next_frame

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your frames no.  41 and 42 seem to be identical. That's why you may not get any optical flow between the two, as there is no difference between the two images.

Comment: @TimeS Thank you soooo much! I compared the two frames, you are right, They did are the same. Problem solved.